# Sharepoint 2013 task list sync to outlook is throwing error

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, outlook, profile-sync

When I try to click on sync to outlook on sharepoint 2013 task list. It is throwing this error:

> We couldn't start syncing your tasks because we need to get a few things set up first. Click here to get started, and then retry syncing your tasks.

When I click on click here link. it is navigating me to "Edit your profile page".

What should I do to fix it.

Comment: I am having Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013.

Comment: Does this issue replicate for all users ?

Comment: Yes. It is throwing the same error for all users.

Answer (score 1):

Found some related information online today as there is some sort of master task list in the "My Site" area of SharePoint. From what I learned from this article is that the "connect to outlook" button tries to point you to the main task list that would be found on your "My Site" SharePoint site (if its enabled). In my case our SharePoint environment does not have all of "my sites" enabled so you cant get it to connect to outlook because the "my site" feature is off.

More info: http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2012/09/sharepoint-2013-task-management-in-my-sites/

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing an error when attempting to sync a SharePoint 2013 task list to Outlook, there are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot the issue:

Check SharePoint and Outlook Versions: Ensure that you are using a compatible version of SharePoint 2013 and Outlook. Verify that both applications are up to date with the latest updates and service packs.

Verify Task List Settings: Confirm that the task list in SharePoint is set up properly for syncing with Outlook. Check that the "Sync to Outlook" option is enabled for the task list. You can find this option under the List Settings in SharePoint.

Clear Outlook Cache: Clearing the Outlook cache can sometimes resolve synchronization issues. Close Outlook, navigate to the Outlook cache folder, and delete the contents. The cache folder location can vary depending on the version of Outlook you are using. Once cleared, restart Outlook and try syncing the task list again.

Repair Office Installation: If the error persists, you can try repairing your Office installation. Open the Control Panel, navigate to Programs, and select Microsoft Office. From there, choose the Repair option and follow the prompts to repair the Office installation. After the repair, attempt to sync the task list to Outlook.

Recreate Outlook Profile: If all else fails, you can try recreating your Outlook profile. This process involves creating a new Outlook profile and configuring it to connect to your email account. Once the new profile is set up, attempt to sync the task list to Outlook again.